# Persistence & Performance of libapache2-mod-log-sql

Tags: mysql, logging, apache2, debian

I have been working on a requirement for our apache2 logs to be recorded to a mysql database, instead of the text log file norm.

I had no difficulty in accomplishing the setup and config, and it works as expected, however there seems to be a bit of information that I cannot find (or may very well be that I am searching for the wrong thing).

Is there anyone out there who use (or even like to use) libapache2-mod-log-sql that are able to tell more about its connection to mysql? Is it persistent? What kind of resource impact should I expect?

These two issues are core to my research, and yet so rare to find info on.

thanks in advance.

Comment: So much time has passed, but it's still rare to find such info.